# What's the iex equivalent of erl's 'rr'?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

In the Erlang shell, `erl`, I can use `rr(Mod)` to load the record definitions from the specified module. This allows me to see the field names when looking at a record in the shell.

What's the equivalent to `rr(Mod)` in the Elixir shell, `iex`?

For example, I've got an `'RSAPrivateKey'` Erlang record, but when shown in `iex`, all I see is:

```
{:RSAPrivateKey,
 <<48, 130, 4, 164, 2, 1, 0, 2, 130, 1, 1, 0, 181, 223, 0, 179, 206, 108, 57,
   72, 227, 146, 53, 117, 218, 232, 204, 33, 153, 161, 201, 232, 23, 145, 201,
   134, 105, 53, 164, 223, 95, 111, 64, 29, 254, 114, 146, 33, ...>>,
 :not_encrypted}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with erlang records, but `Record.extract` and/or `Record.extract_all` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the field names with `record_name(a_record)`:

```
iex(1)> c "user_record.ex"                  
[User]

iex(2)> import User
User

iex(3)> user1 = user()
{:user, "Meg", "25"}

iex(4)> user(user1)
[name: "Meg", age: "25"]

iex(5)> user2 = user(name: "Roger", age: 50)
{:user, "Roger", 50}

iex(6)> user(user2) 
[name: "Roger", age: 50]
```

user_record.ex:

```
defmodule User do
  require Record
  Record.defrecord :user, [name: "Meg", age: "25"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Erlang docs:

> `rr(Module)`
>   Reads record definitions from a module's BEAM file. If there are no record definitions in the BEAM file, the source file is located and read instead. Returns the names of the record definitions read. Module is an atom.

That said, if the code *is already compiled* to BEAMs, you might use `Module.record_name/0` to get an info.

If the code is *not yet compiled*, you still might extract the record information *from erlang header file* `record.hrl` with [`Record.extract/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Record.html#extract/2).